# Prove that $f$ is continuous with respect to $d$ and the standard topology on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

Could anyone help me with the following question. I have been struggling to understand how to go about proving that $f$ is continuous.

Let $A$ be a non-empty bounded subset of the set $M$ and $d$ a distance function 
on $M$.

Let $f$ : $M$ → $\mathbb R$ be the function with
$f$($x$) = sup {$d(x, a)$ $a$ ∈ $A$} .

Prove that $f$ is continuous with respect to $d$ and the standard topology on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and fix some $b \in M$.

Note now that if $d(x,b) < \epsilon$ then, for all $a \in A$ you have
$$d(x,a) \leq d(b,a)+\epsilon \leq f(b)+\epsilon$$
Taking the supremum by $a$ you get
$$f(x) \leq f(b)+\epsilon$$

Now, intechanging $x$ and $b$ you get for all $a \in A$
$$d(b,a) \leq d(x,a)+\epsilon \leq f(x)+\epsilon$$
Taking the supremum by $a$ you get
$$f(b) \leq f(x)+\epsilon$$

**Note** The above actually shows uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: I need help with the following question.

Let ($M, d$) be a metric space and $x$ ∈ $M$. 

Define $D : M × M → \mathbb R$

by $D(p, q)$ =
$d(p, x) + d(q, x)$ if $p$ does not equal $q$

and 

$D(p, q)$ = $0$ if $p=q$

Show that $D$ is a distance function.

My attempt: 

I am aware that this function holds for non-negativity when $p$ does not equal $q$ 

I am also aware that it holds for identification condition as the function = $0$ when $p = q$

How would i show symmetry and and that it holds for the triangle inequality